# How to apply conditional data validation when a cell with a defined value is changed?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, data-validation

I have a spreadsheet that's basically a grid checklist, let's say 10 columns and 20 rows.

There are multiple cells that have `N/A` as the value, and I'm worried going through the checklist that one might accidentally be changed.

So I'd like to protect all cells that equal `N/A` and show a warning if that value is changed. However other cells that do not have `N/A` should not be validated.

Is this possible, without or with a script?

Answer (score 0):

- without a script, you can set up data validation with a custom formula **`=COUNTIF(A1,"=N/A")`**

  [image]
- and then copy **A1** cell,  select all cells in the grid and paste only data validation:

  [image]